# Views with nodes and taxonomy: Cannot group by node nid

Tags: 7, views

I have nodes with field_my_taxonomy_reference

My View is displaying nodes, but I have added such field in fields list:

(my relationship with taxonomy field) Taxonomy term: name

Now, I have duplicates in results. If some node has two taxonomy terms atatched, this node is displayed twice in results. I cannot replace "Taxonomy term" with "Content: field_my_taxonomy_reference", because I need to use Taxonomy term name in Combined field filter.

I tried to use grouping through Format -> parameters but it didn't help. If I grouped by node title, it resulted to following structure in results:

Node title 1:

-- node title 1, node image, tax. term 1

-- node title 1, node image, tax. term 2

Node title 2:

-- node title 2, node image, tax. term 1

-- node title 2, node image,  tax. term 2

I would need to achieve such output:

Node title 1:

--node image

--tax. term 1, tax. term 2

Node title 2:

--node image

--tax. term 1, tax. term 2

I have tried all combinations of checked/unchecked checkboxes "Remove tags from rendered output" and "Use rendered output to group rows"

I tried to use distinct in Query settings, but it didn't help, too. When I trun on aggregation, I get no results in View.

Comment: Try using this relationship: "Taxonomy term: Representative node" and select "Content: Nid" as sort criteria.

Comment: You need to aggregate to achieve your result. I see you say that when you turn it on you get no result. Turn it on and remove all sort filters. Then add a hidden nid field and set aggregation to count on it. Once you get it working you can add sorting filters back.